# Paging with follow less +F and colorize with awk

Tags: awk, logs, colors, less

I would like to paginate a file with follow, i.e. $less +F and also colorize the output on the screen.

I want to use less because I can leave the follow mode, browse the file and then re-enter the follow mode.

I want something like that:

```
#!/bin/sh
tail -f ./StdOutErr.0 | awk -v RS='\r\n' '
/STDOUT/ {print $0}
/STDERR/ {print "\033[38;5;202m" $0 "\033[39m"}
' | less -R +F
```

But it is not working, i just get an empty screen.
Ideas someone?

Comment: sounds like your file doesn't have lines ending `\r\n`. Try `cat -vet` on it and check you see `^M$` at the end of each line.

Comment: You might try using `printf` instead of `print` and specifying the escape character in a more portable fashion.

Comment: My file is a regular file with lines ending. I can see a "...scanning..." in the terminal but still nothing else.

Comment: First check, that this command works without less.

Comment: If the file doesn't contain lines with **`STDOUT`** and **`STDERR`** (literally those strings), awk will print nothing.